# Does Swift have any native concurrency and multi-threading support?

Tags: multithreading, swift, concurrency, native

I'm writing a Swift client to communicate with a server (written in C) on an embedded system. Its not iOS/OSX related as I'm using the recently released Ubuntu version.

Does Swift have any native support for concurrency? I'm aware that Apple discourages developers from using threads and encourages handing tasks over to dispatch queues via GCD. The issue is that GCD seems to be only on  Darwin (and NSThread is a part of Cocoa).

For example, C++11 and Java have threads and concurrency as a part of their standard libraries. I understand that platform specific stuff like posix on unix could be used under some sort of C wrapper, but for me that really ruins the point of using Swift in the first place (clean, easy to understand code etc.).

Comment: try to look at libdispatch for Ubuntu. GCD is really nice concept and easy to use. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdispatch

Comment: The official port of GDC (https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch) is not yet functional on Ubuntu. Is this some port by the Ubuntu guys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 2021 came and...

Starting with Swift 5.5, [more options are available](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html) like async/await programming models and actors.

There is still no direct manipulation of threads, and this is (as of today) a design choice.

> If you’ve written concurrent code before, you might be used to working with threads. The concurrency model in Swift is built on top of threads, but you don’t interact with them directly. An asynchronous function in Swift can give up the thread that it’s running on, which lets another asynchronous function run on that thread while the first function is blocked.

### Original 2015 answer

Quoting from [Swift's GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution), there's a readme for "evolutions" :

> **Concurrency**: Swift 3.0 relies entirely on platform concurrency primitives (libdispatch, Foundation, pthreads, etc.) for concurrency. Language support for concurrency is an often-requested and potentially high-value feature, but is too large to be in scope for Swift 3.0.

I guess this means no language-level "primitives" for threading are in the pipeline for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Makes sense. I suppose it's some consolation that Apple is actively building a Linux version of GDC as part of its open sourcing.

Comment: Of course. Still, seeing what Scala (and Java, and Python) do with `Future`-like constructs (and composition... and all the likes), and seeing the language designer's taste for borrowing features form such languages, one could see the value in extending Swift, beyond "just" porting GCD.

Comment: Yeah absolutely. The inclusion of functional programming constructs from languages such as Ruby and Scala to a type safe, C based language forms a large part of Swift's attraction for me (and others, no doubt).